# How can I fix (no such column : availability) error ??? When I run this code I get this error :no such column : availability

Tags: python, database, sqlite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pypNV.png)I want to update a record in SQLite database when I run this code I get an error "no such column : availability"!!!
What is the problem ???
How can I fix this ???

```
def Update_ID ():

    # connect to database if exist or if doesnt exit create one

     conn= sqlite3.connect("Books_table.bd")

     #create cursors
     Cursor = conn.cursor()

     #Insert new value instead of old one in the table 
     Cursor.execute("""UPDATE books SET
        book_name =  :bookname ,
        book_number = :booknumber ,
        book_writer = :bookwriter,
        book_subject = :booksubject,
        available_num = :availablenum,
        availability = :Availability ,
        barrower = :Barrower ,
        return_date = :returndate
        WHERE oid = :oid """,
        {
        'bookname': b_name_editor1.get() ,
        'booknumber' : b_num_editor1.get() ,
        'bookwriter' : b_writer_editor1.get(),
        'booksubject' : Subject_editor1.get(),
        'availablenum' : available_num_editor1.get(),
        'Availability': var.get() ,
        'Barrower' : borrower.get(),
        'returndate' : ID_FIND.Returndate_editor1.get(),
        "oid" : Select.Book_ID_editor.get()})


    #Commit changes
    conn.commit()
    #close database
     conn.close()
```

Comment: You've misspelled `availability` as `availablity`.  You're missing the `i` immediately after the `b`.

Comment: yes I fixed it but It still give me an error

Comment: Then the obvious answer is that the `books` table does not have an `availability` column.  Can you show us the table definition for `books`?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pypNV.png here is the table definition

Comment: Okay, so it's actually misspelled in the table definition.  It should have worked as you originally posted it.

Comment: But I do not think it is related to the wrong spelling because it does not work in any case